# GCC inline assembly error

Tags: inline-assembly

I'm trying to convert inline assembly code using nano textfile in Linux.

```
__asm__ ("MOV AX, morales1\n\t" 
         "MOV BX, morales2\n\t;"
         "ADD AX, BX\n\t;"
         "MOV morales, AX;" 
        );
```

With morales 1 and 2 being signed shorts. I get the following error:

> "Error: ARM register expected -- mov AX,morales1'"`

Comment: Are you working on an ARM chip?  You'll want the documentation for the chip architecture which will provide the valid register names. AX may not be for the given target architecture.  You might start here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.qrc0001m/QRC0001_UAL.pdf

Comment: ARM processors need ARM assembly code, not x86 assembly code.

Comment: yeah i am. im working with a raspberry pi. so the format is incorrect? like the registers?

Comment: i copy and pasted from an inline assembly code in C and tried to transfer it into a Kano text editor in linux. the c part of the code goes through but i just get errors in the inline asembly

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit fuzzy on what a compiler does.  At its simplest, a c compiler takes files with c instructions and converts them into assembly language instructions appropriate for executing on a specific processor.

But there are a lot of processors out there, and every family of processors use different assembly instructions.  How can a c compiler cope with that?  The answer is that a given compiler (typically) only supports a single output format.  So you might have a compiler that outputs code for x86, another one outputs x64, one for ARM, MIPS, etc.  While they all take a c language input file, they each output the appropriate assembler instructions for its target.

This means that regular c instructions (case, break, printf, scanf, etc) the compiler can translate to appropriate assembler for you.  However when you use the `asm` instruction, you are telling the compiler NOT to perform any c->assembler translation.  It must output exactly the specific assembler instructions you are providing.

What does all this have to do with your question?

What do you suppose happens if you take the assembler instructions from one platform (say x86) and try to use it on another platform (say ARM)?  Well, mostly what happens is that it doesn't work.  (As a fictitious example) if you try to use `add x, y` and the processor expects `u32.xadd x, x, y`, it's going to get really confused, and just treat your assembler as nonsense.

So, how do you 'fix' this?  Well, the most sensible plan would be to stop trying to use assembly language in your c code.  It looks like you are just trying to add 2 numbers.  c already has instructions that can do that.

To emphasize: Writing c code and letting the compiler output code is almost always the better approach.  Trying to use inline assembly requires that you know c language, the assembly language for your target processor, and the interface rules between the two that your specific compiler has chosen to use (each compiler seems to do this slightly differently).  That's a lot to know and try to get right.  And (as you have discovered) it makes moving from one compiler/processor to another painful.

But if you absolutely **must** use assembler, you need to start by learning the assembler instructions for your processor.  A google search should turn up a variety of resources for these instructions.  Once you have learned that, you can update your `asm` command to contain the correct instructions.